# How to disable release upgrade notification emails?

Tags: upgrade, email, notification

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 server installation that consistently sends a weekly email, from the root user, with the following content:

```
/etc/cron.weekly/update-notifier-common:
New release '16.04.1 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
```

How do I stop these emails, without upgrading to 16.04? Is there a method that doesn't involve disabling the script mentioned in the first line of the email?

Ideally I'd like to allow `/etc/cron.weekly/update-notifier-common` to continue to run, calling the `/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-motd` and `/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release` scripts, but stop new release messages. It would be useful for these scripts to still warn if my current release becomes EOL.

Comment: It seems to check whether `/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-motd` exists and runs it if not.

Comment: sorry yes I looked, and that runs `/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release` if there is a new release, and that is a python3 script that I am guessing is responsible for bothering you... but I have 16.10 so maybe it is not the same

Answer (score 4):

By default `cron` sends mail to the email address mentioned in the `MAILTO` environment variable on `crontab`, presumably you have set the email address, so any STDOUT/STDERR from any `cron` job will be sent to the email address.

The output is from `/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-motd` script (run by the weekly job `/etc/cron.weekly/update-notifier-common`) that checks for a new version, and dump the content of `/var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available` file.

You have a few options:

- Disable the job
- Redirect STDOUT/STDERR from the script to `/dev/null`
- Set `MAILTO=""` so that no mail will be sent. As `/usr/sbin/anacron` exists the script will be run by `anacron`, so setting this in `/etc/anacrontab` would do too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, definitely don't want to disable emails from cron entirely. Ideally I'd like to be able to ask it to stop telling me about new releases, but still do its other tasks, like warning when my version is out of support. Not sure that's possible though.

Comment: @Arronical Thats what the script is doing.

Comment: I understand that the script is responsible for that, but wondered if it's possible to stop the new release warning, while keeping the rest of the functionality.

Comment: @Arronical It is (almost) the only thing it does, except running upgrading in the background.

Answer (score 2):

I'm still testing if this works, but first I set

```
/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

to `Prompt=never`

Then you need to empty the notification by running:

```
echo -n "" > /var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available
```

Comment: This appeared to work for me. After waiting a week, I have not gotten any more emails.

Answer (score 1):

Since the /etc/update-motd.d/91-release-upgrade -script checks whether the following file is executable

```
/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-motd
```

a simple fix for this is to remove execute -flags from the file by running the following command

```
chmod a-x /usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-motd
```

Comment: Will this produce an error message? If so that will generate an email that I'd like to avoid.

Comment: @Arronical - it will not produce an error, since `/etc/cron.weekly/update-notifier-common` checks the executability flag of that file and exits if it's not executable.