# Stop cron emailing me about 20.04 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, cron, email

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 cloud server. Every week lately I get an email from cron reminding me that there's an upgrade to 20.04 available.

I get it, cron. I really do.

I'd like to stop this reminder only without disabling cron emails in general. How can I notify my buddy cron that I'm aware of the upgrade and they can stop emailing me about it?

Comment: ;-( what did you expect if you deliverd your soul and your hardware and your data to the gods of the cloud? ;-(

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a duplicate of: [How to disable release upgrade notification emails?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/843778/how-to-disable-release-upgrade-notification-emails)
While this is for 14.04 the general guideline should hold still, in particular - stopping that one job in `cron`.

**Top answer:**

By default `cron` sends mail to the email address mentioned in the `MAILTO` environment variable on `crontab`, presumably you have set the email address, so any STDOUT/STDERR from any `cron` job will be sent to the email address.

The output is from `/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-motd` script (run by the weekly job `/etc/cron.weekly/update-notifier-common`) that checks for a new version, and dump the content of /var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available file.

You have a few options:

- Disable the job
- Redirect `STDOUT/STDERR` from the script to `/dev/null`
- Set `MAILTO=""` so that no mail will be sent. As `/usr/sbin/anacron` exists the script will be run by anacron, so setting this in `/etc/anacrontab` would do too.

Comment: Is there no way to tell the "upgrade available" notification system to stop?  What if I delete the `release-upgrade-motd` script, or make it not executable?

Comment: And thanks, I agree it's a a duplicate. Probably should have vtc instead of answering.